# can't copy exact bootstrap template from there website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

i am trying co copy a template from bootstrap.com but it doesn't copy exactly the same.

nav become white from black and i can't change the colour and i have also a problem with the toogle button

```
<header>
  <div class="collapse bg-inverse" id="navbar-Header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 py-4">
          <h4 class="text-white">About</h4>
          <p class="text-muted">Add some information about the album below, the author, or any other background context. Make it a few sentences long so folks can pick up some informative tidbits. Then, link them off to some social networking sites or contact information.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
          <h4 class="text-white">Contact</h4>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Like on Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Email me</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div id="nav">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark black"></nav>  
            <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
              <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="mr-2"><path d="M23 19a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4l2-3h6l2 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="13" r="4"></circle></svg>
                <strong>Album</strong>
              </a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
        </nav> 
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you give us the url of the template you try to copy ? Currently it cannot work, you only copied the HTML and forgot to copy the CSS...

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/album/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't copy the Bootstrap's CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that all css and js libraries of bootstrap are loaded correctly. Please try this layout. You should know that this layout includes jquery slim that is not compatible with ajax, if you planinig to use ajax, you should prefer jquery min.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you brother it worked i wil never forget your help. i was trying for 6 hours and you solved it seconds.